# Semver on nested object in JavaScript, major, minor or patch?

Tags: javascript, versioning, semantic-versioning

I thought I was pretty clued up on [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) but this one change has made me unsure on what is the expected version change:

The original code:

```
if (result.error) {
  return callback(result.error);
}
```

The new code:

```
if (result.error) {
  result.error.message = `${result.error.message} on ${self.tableName()}`;
  return callback(result.error);
}
```

I'm thinking this change could be classed as a `patch`, `minor` or as a `major` change. The three scenarios:

1. `patch`: the callback is still receiving an `Error` object. The `Error` object still has a `message` property and that property is still a `String`.
2. `minor`: a consumer may be relying on the contents of the `message` property, looking for a part of the string. This change just adds more to the end of the string, therefore is just additive.
3. `major`: a consumer may be relying on the contents of the `message` property and this is now a different string

I got really angry once when a library I was using didn't conform to semver in the way I was expecting. I don't want to do that to somebody else.

I'm conscious this could be viewed as a subjective/opinion based question but I'm looking for the 'correct' answer (with evidence if possible). The safest option is obviously to go for `major` but I'm looking to see if that's overkill.

Comment: Because you can't know how your users are using the message, it's a breaking change.

Comment: @AdrianLynch then *every* change is a breaking change.

Comment: Of course not. If I add a new method, it's not a breaking change. If I add an extra argument to a method, it's not a breaking change. If I return something different to before, it's a potentially breaking change.

Comment: @Clarkie - Why not just bump the major version? What's wrong with doing that?

Comment: @AdrianLynch I guess the negative side of that is that it will prompt consumers to have to dig in to find out what's changed. Most people automatically update minor and patch versions but not majors. I think the best explanation for using patch was that if the error message string isn't documented then it shouldn't be relied upon as part of the api. This makes it a patch change

Comment: @AdrianLynch "If I add a new method, it's not a breaking change" --- it surely is: if a code checks for a method presence - and you change it from "there is no method" to "there is a method" there definitely is a breaking change. "If I add an extra argument to a method, it's not a breaking change" -- the same here. If a client's code relies on number of arguments you accept (via reflection) then you're again breaking their code. They may even rely on the name of the arguments you use.

Comment: Then according to your logic, there are no changes that aren't breaking. No need for semver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Patch`

Did you have to change any of your tests when you did this, to accommodate the change? I suspect not. If you weren't relying on this message format then what are the chances of your consumers relying on it?

Comment: I went for patch in the end. The error messages weren't documented and so shouldn't have been relied on.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the context - is there a way of getting the information that's contained within the error message without string manipulation? If so, I'd say changing it is not a breaking change - you shouldn't have to bend over backwards to support code that's using the API in unsupported ways.

On the other hand, if there's no other way of getting that info, then that's an issue with your API. In that case, I'd recommend pushing a major version with the new message and methods/properties on the error object for getting that information - this would avoid breaking people's code, and ensure you don't have to deal with this issue again if you want to change the error message.